# How to get a default text display from a dropdown menu on selecting a value from a dropdown menu from another text box?

Tags: javascript

My jsp page has the code below for two fields(Form and Mode) which have dropdown menu. The value is got from xml tables in Database. If I select a specific payment method in Form it should show a default value in Mode. This jsp page has javascript loaded to it. How do I call a function in JS and proceed. Kindly help as I am new to JavaScript.

```html
<td width="18%">Form</td>
<td width="25%">
  <stphtml:select property="value(paymentMethod)" delegate="refresh" size="1" tabindex="3">
    <html:optionsCollection name="AVMContainer" property="avCollection(PaymentMethod)" value="value" label="label" />
  </stphtml:select>
</td>

<td width="18%" colspan="2">Mode</td>
<td width="19%">
  <stphtml:select property="value(paymentMode)" delegate="refresh" size="1" tabindex=42 ">
    <html:optionsCollection name="AVMContainer " property="avCollection(PaymentMode) " value="value " label="label " />
  </stphtml:select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'mySelect' is id of your dropdown:

```
  var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var selectedText = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text;
```